# Term for a one-row table?

Tags: oracle, db2, firebird, terminology

Is there a specific term to describe a relation with a cardinality of one?

I'm thinking particularly of RDBMS "special" one-row tables, for example, `DUAL` (Oracle), `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` (DB2, Derby) and `RDB$DATABASE` (Interbase, Firebird).

Comment: Interesting question, I've come across these in some vendor databases, usually "settings" tables

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Singleton Table. In relational terms it is a relation with primary key ∅ (the empty set).

Comment: +1  A colleague suggested this moniker, too.  (He also suggested "highlander table," which has a certain charm.)

Comment: That's a [singleton table](https://www.facebook.com/IKEAMalaysia/photos/a.246919612026392.77953.239569229428097/747069108678104/?type=1&theater), too.